# How can I combine groupby + condition + some operation, when using pandas?

Tags: pandas

Given the following dataframe -

```
    id  value  is_mapping
0   1      1           1
1   1      1           1
2   1      1           0
3   2      1           0
4   2      1           0
5   2      1           0
6   3      1           1
7   3      1           1
8   3      1           1
```

I want to groupby id and sum the values of each `id`, and only those when `is_mapping == 1`

The result should be -

```
   id  sum_result
0   1           2
1   2           0
2   3           3
```

Is there a way to do that without apply?

Answer (score 1):

Making a reasonable assumption that the `is_mapping` column would only take 0/1 values :

```py
(df['value'] * df['is_mapping']).groupby(df['id']).sum().reset_index(name='sum_result')
   id  sum_result
0   1           2
1   2           0
2   3           3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set `0` for values not match conditiona and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df['value'].where(df['is_mapping'].eq(1), 0)
                  .groupby(df['id'])
                  .sum()
                  .reset_index(name='sum_result'))
print (df1)
   id  sum_result
0   1           2
1   2           0
2   3           3
```

Or create helper column with same idea:

```
df1 = (df.assign(sum_result=df['value'].where(df['is_mapping'].eq(1), 0))
         .groupby('id', as_index=False)['sum_result']
         .sum())
print (df1)
   id  sum_result
0   1           2
1   2           0
2   3           3
```

Another solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add not exist groups with `0` values:

```
df1 = (df[df['is_mapping'].eq(1)]
         .groupby('id')['value']
         .sum()
         .reindex(df['id'].unique(), fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(name='sum_result'))
print (df1)
   id  sum_result
0   1           2
1   2           0
2   3           3
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, using `numpy`:

```
a = df.values
id = np.unique(a[:,0])

pd.DataFrame({
    'id': id, 
    'sum_result': [np.sum(a[a[:,0] == x, 1] * a[a[:,0] == x,2]) for x in id]})
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
(df['id'].to_frame()
 .merge(df.loc[df['is_mapping'].astype(bool)]
        .groupby('id')['value'].sum(), on='id', how='left')
 .drop_duplicates().fillna(0).rename({'value': 'sum_result'}, axis=1))
```

---

Output:

```
   id  sum_result
0   1         2.0
3   2         0.0
6   3         3.0
```